# extra column showing where, using temporay, using file sort in mdn table. Where to apply proper index

Tags: mysql

```
explain extended SELECT c . id , c . city_name , 
c . area_code , c . country_id ,
 c . is_mvoo , c . is_byoo FROM city c , 
mdn m WHERE c . id = m . city_id AND c . whitelabel_partner_id =5  AND
 c . active = 'Y' AND c . country_id = 73 AND m . MDN_state_id = 7 GROUP BY
 m . city_id HAVING COUNT( m . city_id ) > 50
ORDER BY c . sorting , c . city_name;
```

Any one tell me on which columns I should apply indices to in order to get rid of using temporary and using filesort.

Comment: Can you paste the table structure (CREATE TABLE statements) and the result of "explain extended" into your question?

Comment: can you please tell me which columns i should use for indices.

Comment: In Addition to `EXPLAIN` an `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` will just return the query as it is seen by the optimizer (as a warning). `EXPLAIN` will do in this case

Comment: [You can't always get rid of "using temporary" and "using filesort".](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44627/1064)

Answer (score 0):

Put a combined Index on the constant columns fist, then add the Join-Column in the Index. You dont have to add an index on both tables since MySQL will only use one of them.

```
 ALTER TABLE City ADD INDEX combIdx_1 (whitelabel_partner_id, active, country_id, id)
```

Add

```
 ... UNIQUE INDEX ...
```

If the combination of all cols is unique.